# Using the same toggle for multiple graphs in NVD3 with rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts

I would like to create more than one multiBarChart using the `nPlot` function. For all these graphs the legend has the same groups and I would like arrange them so that I can use only a toggle that works for all the plots simultaneously. Do you know if it is possible to create a sort of grid that can do what I need?